# How do we add the members to the repo team in GitHub via Email Id

Tags: c#, api, github, octokit.net

I want to sent an invite to GitHub user to join any particular team in any Organization based on email id.

Currently, I am able to sent an invite for same but using GitHub Username using Octokit Library method

```
AddOrEditMembership(id, name, role)
```

Is there any function(Octokit library) or API which will help to sent an invite using Email Id

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any function(Octokit library) or API which will help to sent an invite using Email Id

On Octokit, apparently not.
[`octokit/octokit.net` `Octokit/Clients/RepoCollaboratorsClient.cs#Invite()`](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/356588288e2d07fb4844911f6e03ef129540b124/Octokit/Clients/RepoCollaboratorsClient.cs#L355-L432) methods alwats use a username, not email.

And it reflects the [Add Collaborator API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/collaborators/collaborators#add-a-repository-collaborator=), which is also based on username.